# Toilet leaking at mounting bolts when flushed

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain, flange

I have replaced two wax rings and I still get an ounce of water up from the Johnny bolt on the right side.

I replaced the flange, had to chisel out an old rotten cast iron flange, inserted a plastic flange with triple gaskets to seal. Tried a few different wax/ring combinations and at last  , it still leaks a little when flushed.

All out of options,  any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain of where the water is coming from? Water likes to travel. Last week, I had water coming out of the seal between the tank and the toilet every time the toilet was flushed based on the water refilling and disturbing the old crumbling gasket (it made a reasonable seal when the tank was full). I replaced just the float valve intake for the first try since that seemed to be where the water was coming from (really, the bottom of the valve was just where the water happened to collect) before I finally figured out the root cause of my leak.

Comment: Put food dye in the *bowl*, then flush. If the leaking water is the color of the dye, then the water is coming from the bowl. If the leaked water is colorless, then do it again to make sure that un-dyed water originally from the bowl wasn't trapped under the toilet.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you have a small crack on the bottom of the toilet that's letting water seep past the wax ring, you have a leak from the tank, or the wax ring is not sealing properly.  Also check to see that it is vented properly and that you don't have anything trapped in the drain

Comment: Wax rings sometimes do decay to uselessness over time. Not often, but if you haven't replaced one in twenty years the day may be coming.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it could be a crack as Merrill has suggested. But with 3 gaskets I would not expect it to seal, I have seen 2 work. What is needed is to install a compression flange 25-50$ depending on brand / quality. If this is how you repaired the first time cut the cast off a bit further down and install plastic pipe and flange at the correct level so only 1 gasket is needed. When I have needed to cut the cast further down I will usually cut about mid level in the crawl space to provide working space.